# No interaction with Facebook iOS SDK dialog after switching to thread?

Tags: iphone, facebook, multithreading, sdk

I'm playing around a little bit with the Facebook iOS SDK.

I have a TabBar App (with MainWindow.xib) and I successfully integrated the Facebook SDK.

The problem is that non of the Facebook pop up dialogs are responding to my user interactions.

For example. I want to post something in the wall. The Facebook SDK opens a dialog but if i try to interacte with the dialog it doesn't happen anything.

The log tells me: [Switching to process 2365 thread 0x12d07]

How can I fix it?

I'm using the simulator.

The important code int the AppDelegate looks like that, it's actually more or less the same like on developer.facebook.com:

Thank you a lot.

```
// AppDelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate, FBDialogDelegate> {
    Facebook *facebook;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;


// AppDelegate.m

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize facebook;

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"APP_ID" andDelegate:self];

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Kind regards.

Comment: You probably want to edit your question and add some code (or pseudo code) around the problem, otherwise folks are just guessing what you problems are. You should also share how you've debugged it so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need a method that posts to a feed, like the one below

```
-(void)postToFeed
{
    MyAppAppDelegate *sharedAppDelegate = (MyAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [sharedAppDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this same problem. The problem for me was that my UIApplication keyWindow had userInteractionEnabled = NO. So not having that extra UIWindow present fixed it for me (more below).

I found this code in FBDialog.m

```
- (void)showWebView {   
    UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow; 
    if (!window) {  
        window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];   
    }   
    _modalBackgroundView.frame = window.frame;  
    [_modalBackgroundView addSubview:self]; 
    [window addSubview:_modalBackgroundView];   
    ....
```

so it's going to add the dialog to the keyWindow. I only had one window, so I thought. It turns out SVProgressHUD will create a new window with user interaction disabled and make it the key window (makes sense).

I'm guessing other HUD style things do this to. I was only showing the HUD while some prep work was done, so by the time I can show the dialog, I can remove it anyway. So that was my fix.

I dug this up by calling

```
    NSLog(@"%@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow);
```

right before I was about to show the dialog and noticed

- I had two UIWindow's
- the key one's userInteractionEnabled was set to NO

Hope that helps.